# Xamarin Socket backend

Tags: .net, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.forms, socket.io

I'm trying to implement an app in Xamarin and make use of a nice socket back end taking care of all the socket implementation details and allowing me to actually focus on my app.

However, I'm very much confused about the current state of the art and the whole .Net ecosystem. What I understood so far is that [PCL seems to be deprecated](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/113858/pcl-no-longer-a-viable-solution). Thus, I decided against using [this nice solution](https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl) and go for a Xamarin app based on .NET Standard instead.

I read somewhere that [SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) is a nice alternative but unfortunately I'm not able to install its nuget package. This is the message I always end up with:

```
NU1202: Package SocketIoClientDotNet 1.0.7.1 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package SocketIoClientDotNet 1.0.7.1 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.1067413
========== Finished ==========
```

Other solutions I found are mainly built for web sockets, which is not what I want to use as I aim for a simple TCP client to server connection. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed from here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/1iveowl/SocketLite

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.